Stepfunction pass variables from json to aws batch container
I am creating a stepfunction that submits a batch job with terraform.
I am facing an issue with environment variables. Here I am passing 2 variables $IMAGE and $ENV and are getting overwritten correctly.
My problem is that I have over 20 variables, and each time I have to pass a set of different variables (a json of 2 variables or 5 or maybe 10).
How to pass directly those variables from json to container without having to define the 20 variables in this container ContainerOverrides ?
Because if I define the 20 variables like these 2, step functions throws an error:

The JSONPath '$.SERVER' specified for the field 'SERVER.$' could not
be found in the input

and the reason I am getting this error is I just defined 2 variables in the json input I passed to the step function.
A very bad solution would be to always pass 20 variables in my json (the ones I use are correctly set, others have null value
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "state_machine" {
  count = length(local.batch_list)

  name     = "state-machine"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.sfn_role.arn

  definition = jsonencode({
    Comment = "A description of my state machine",
    StartAt = "Batch SubmitJob",
    States = {
      "Batch SubmitJob" = {
        Type     = "Task",
        Resource = "arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync",
        Parameters = {
          JobDefinition = aws_batch_job_definition.job_definition,
          JobName       = "job",
          JobQueue      = aws_batch_job_queue.queue,
          ContainerOverrides = {
            Environment = [
            {
            Name      = "IMAGE",
            "Value.$" = "$.IMAGE"
            },
            {
            Name      = "ENV",
            "Value.$" = "$.ENV"
            }
            ]
          }
        }
        End = true
      }
    }
  })
}


you nust explian what is your end goal. You can use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/batch_job_definition.
